# ERROR :- Undefined variable: raw While Transfering data between 2 pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

```
manageleavetype.php
```

Below code is my first file page I want to redirect this page form content into next file code edit.php. I want want to update the data from the next page.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $des; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
<input type="hidden" name="hid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="htype" value="<?php echo $type; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hdes" value="<?php echo $des; ?>">
<td><input type="submit" name="del" value="DELETE">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="UPDATE">
</td></form></tr>
```

edit.php

This file except the code from above file and update the data that is received into MySQL database

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $eid = $_POST['hid'];
    $que = "SELECT * FROM leavetype WHERE id='$eid'";
    $exe = mysqli_query($conn, $que);
    $raw = mysqli_fetch_array($exe);
}

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $nwtype = $_POST['ltype'];
    $nwdes = $_POST['ldes'];

    $que = "UPDATE leavetype SET leavetype='$nwtype',description='$nwdes' WHERE id='$eid'";
    $exe = mysqli_query($conn, $que);
    if ($exe) {
        header("location:manageleavetype.php");
    }
}

?>
<form method="POST">
<label>Leave Type</label>
<input type="text" name="ltype" value="<?php echo $raw['leavetype']; ?>">
<label>Description</label>
<input type="text" name="ldes" value="<?php echo $raw['description']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">

</form>
```

When I run this program following error is coming:

> Notice: Undefined variable: raw in C:\wamp64\www\eLeaveSystem\edit.php on line 31

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

When you only define variables within an `if` block, you risk getting that error. In your case you define `$raw` only when `update` is posted:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $eid = $_POST['hid'];
    $que = "SELECT * FROM leavetype WHERE id='$eid'";
    $exe = mysqli_query($conn, $que);
    $raw = mysqli_fetch_array($exe);
}
```

But you access that variable unconditionally in the HTML generation part, like here:

```
<input type="text" name="ltype" value="<?php echo $raw['leavetype']; ?>">
```

So you have a few options:

1. Put the HTML generation part also in such an `if` block. Then you need to have another part in your code where you generate output for when no `update` is posted.
2. Define default values for those variables. For example `$raw = ['leavetype' => 'something', 'description' => 'default description']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve this issue by using the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to avoid undefined variable issue.

Try below:

```
<form method="POST">
    <label>Leave Type</label>
    <input type="text" name="ltype" value="<?php echo (isset($raw['leavetype']) ? $raw['leavetype'] : '');?>">
    <label>Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="ldes" value="<?php echo (isset($raw['description']) ? $raw['description'] : ''); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
</form>
```

> I assume that the form block should appear for both Update and Insert.